# Trying to read Text File from Uri Android

Tags: java, android, file

I created an android file chooser that returns the uri of a text file. I want to open and read the file and store it's data.My code is:

```
private void covertFile(Uri data) {

        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        String myText = "";
        int in;
        try {
            in = inputStream.read();
            while (in != -1)
            {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(in);
                in = inputStream.read();
            }
            inputStream.close();

            myText = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myTextView.setText(myText);
    }
```

But the line `InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data);` gives`java.Io.FileNotFoundException`. How do I resolve this?

**EDIT: Issue Resolved**

Comment: What do you pass in URI? Make sure the file is available in the given path.

Comment: If the URI refers to a file on device storage you still need android app permissions to read from external storage.

Comment: @Elemental I added permission for reading from external storage

Comment: What is the value of `data.toString()` ? You should have started with that! And it is asked in the first comment already.

Comment: `givesjava.Io.FileNotFoundException` Yes. And also it tells you the path of the not found file. Dont omit this info! Give it us!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First create file object

```
    String path = data.toString();
    File file = new File(path);
```

Now pass the file object as arg in InputStream

```
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(file);
```

Comment: The line ```String path = data.uri.toString();``` and ```File file = new File(new URI(path));``` shows syntax errors.

Comment: Sorry still the same for `File file = new File(new URI(path)); `

Comment: That should be File file = new File(path); of course. Please tell the value of path.

Comment: `InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(file);` One cannot give a File object as parameter there. Better `InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data);` Well .. if data is an URI object.